# Would anyone "decipher" this CAPTCHA for me, please?

Tags: support, search, captcha

At the site [Movies & TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com) I just searched for a keyword, and the page sent me to a Human verification page with a CAPTCHA image. Unfortunately, I couldn't determine the correct words. Here are some samples:

[image: example CAPTCHA][image: example CAPTCHA]
Because the captcha changes for every failed attempt, I do not have a second chance with one. Now I am struck here at this captcha:

[image: example CAPTCHA]

Would anyone care to tell me what these letters are so I can complete my request?

When I do a search the SE server displays a verification page.
But I can solve those because they are simple like this one:

[image: example simple CAPTCHA]

or some simple images with text. But the first three CAPTCHAs in this question are much more difficult (at least for me).

Why do some SE sites use much more difficult CAPTCHAs compared to others? (And of course very often while searching)

Comment: It's obvoiusly nvtrnmth fruntm, robot.

Comment: @Won't In the rear future, captchas would be useless, because, robots would be asking questions to the community to assist them in recognising the captcha. And, the community will be asisting them?

Comment: @Martijn **marked as duplicate by Martijn Pieters**, so what the provided question doesn't solve it. [**'It is working as designed as far as I can tell.'**] [http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248331/278647], of-course it is, it can very well stop bots, as well as some users of SE like me.

Comment: @RogUE: yet the question is the same; Google's reCaptcha is throwing up impassable roadblocks sometimes.

Comment: @RogUE: I agree the text is nigh unreadable, but that doesn't mean we need to open up 20 more questions just because a core developer thinks it is working as designed.

Comment: @RogUE: and I can see his point; from the Stack Exchange side nothing much can be done about Google's choices for the tests.

Comment: So is my response! The SE people could not stop this from happening. I have failed 5+ times and I thought I would touch 100+ before posting this qestion.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Whenever I do a search without loging in, it triggers a verification, why it is so? I am facing this since I joined this network.

Comment: @RogUE: [Why am I being redirected to a captcha when I am just searching?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253524), all anonymous search is gated with a captcha. Just log in.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That is certainly not a good way to welcome someone( First impression is th. ...........). I could not think it as a security measure,could it be?

Comment: It's a way to prevent bots from stealing our mindthoughts.  Or, it may be that certain actions are more burdensome on the system, and to prevent them from being abused by script kiddies, DDOSers, and other losers, you put a robot-proof gate in front of it?  It's either one or the other.  If we knew you weren't a bot, robot, it wouldn't be necessary. We can't know for sure, so you get the captcha.  Or maybe SE *does know* you're a bot?  Hmmm, think about that one for awhile.

Comment: @Won't - Did you just try to free the mind of a self-aware yet closed minded AI bot?

Comment: One time, I had one that did not contain any text at all. And many of them are very hard to read. Strangely enough, I never failed one yet. I started thinking that they let you pass if you're close enough, even if you get a couple of letters wrong.